# how to call devise methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

i create controller:

```
class SigninController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
  def create
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
    if @user 
      ....
      sign_in(:user, @user)
    else
      @user = User.new(params...)
      @user.save
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Correctly i call sign_in method?

signin/index.html.erb:

```
<h2>Sign in</h2>
<%= form_for(User.new, :as => :user, :url => "signin") do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>
  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>
  <br>
  <div><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></div>
<% end %>
```

How to call devise sign_in and sign_up methods of devise?

Comment: Are you trying to manually write the sign-in form, and the code that signs you in? Devise does that for you. You don't have to write that stuff yourself.

Comment: i want login user and create user in one page, on this i made ​​my controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_create_path_for(resource)
    sign_in(:user, resource)
  end 
end
```

That's just kind of a guess. I don't know if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You may but in most cases you should not create custom controller to sign in / out user. Devise has sessions_controller which implements this functionality for you. View [devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and wiki, it has plenty of documentation. Also you can found out there how to customise views and controller behaviour.

**Update**

If need to place both forms (login and registrations) on one view you can customise devise view. Form actions may point to different standard controllers. I suggest to use users/registrations/new form for base form and add uses/sessions/new form to it.

Comment: i want login user and create user in one page, on this i made ​​my controller

Comment: i want place one form(login and password) and if the email already exists it logs the user in. If the email does not exist then it creates a new user using those credentials.

Comment: i add line user = User.new(params[:user]) and user.save and work registration.